# Confusing about the domain of $f(x)=(x+|x|)\sqrt{x\sin^2(\pi x)}$

Tags: calculus, functions

What is the domain of $f(x)=(x+|x|)\sqrt{x\sin^2(\pi x)}$? A nice plot of $f(x)$ shows that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$

[image]

but we see that $x$ should be non-negative at the first sight. Of course, I see that when $x<0$ then the part $x+|x|$ gets vanished and so there is no worry about the another part. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: IMO, the domain shouldn't include the negative numbers, because the square root is undefined. Maybe the program is computing $x+|x|$ part before evaluating the square root, so it doesn't recognize it as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is $D_f=[0, +\infty[$. We can [extend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Restrictions_and_extensions) $f$ to another function $g:~\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\geq0$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x<0$. Of course $g$ is continuous at $x=0$.